# Fedora update problems

Tags: fedora, repository, dnf

i try to update my Fedora 37 system before i can upgrade it to Fedora 38.
Unfortunatlky i#m not really in the topic of repositories and cryptic repo-errors.

Could someone tell me how to fix those few errors?

Thanks a lot.

```
me@system:~>sudo dnf update
Copr repo for element owned by taw                                                                 280  B/s | 341  B     00:01
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:taw:element':
- Status code: 404 for https://download.copr.fedorainfracloud.org/results/taw/element/fedora-37-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 52.222.214.128)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:taw:element': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
Paketquellen werden ignoriert: copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:taw:element
Letzte Prüfung auf abgelaufene Metadaten: vor 1:36:31 am Mo 01 Jan 2024 11:52:12 CET.
Abhängigkeiten sind aufgelöst.

Problem 1: package qt5-qtwebengine-freeworld-5.15.12-3.fc37.x86_64 from @System requires qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.15.9, but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both qt5-qtbase-5.15.10-9.fc37.x86_64 from updates and qt5-qtbase-5.15.9-3.fc37.x86_64 from @System
- Installation des besten Update-Kandidaten nicht möglich für das Paket qt5-qtwebengine-freeworld-5.15.12-3.fc37.x86_64
- Installation des besten Update-Kandidaten nicht möglich für das Paket qt5-qtbase-5.15.9-3.fc37.x86_64
Problem 2: unixODBC-2.3.11-1.fc37.i686 from @System  does not belong to a distupgrade repository
- cannot install both unixODBC-2.3.11-1.rh.x86_64 from packages-microsoft-com-prod and unixODBC-2.3.11-1.fc37.x86_64 from @System
- cannot install both unixODBC-2.3.11-1.rh.x86_64 from packages-microsoft-com-prod and unixODBC-2.3.11-1.fc37.x86_64 from fedora
- Installation des besten Update-Kandidaten nicht möglich für das Paket unixODBC-2.3.11-1.fc37.i686
- Installation des besten Update-Kandidaten nicht möglich für das Paket unixODBC-2.3.11-1.fc37.x86_64
Problem 3: Problem mit installiertem Paket qt5-qtwebengine-freeworld-5.15.12-3.fc37.x86_64
- package qt5-qtwebengine-freeworld-5.15.12-3.fc37.x86_64 from @System requires qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.15.9, but none of the providers can be installed
- package qt5-qtwebengine-freeworld-5.15.12-3.fc37.x86_64 from rpmfusion-free-updates requires qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.15.9, but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both qt5-qtbase-5.15.10-9.fc37.x86_64 from updates and qt5-qtbase-5.15.9-3.fc37.x86_64 from @System
- package keepassxc-2.7.6-2.fc37.x86_64 from updates requires qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.15.10, but none of the providers can be installed
- Installation des besten Update-Kandidaten nicht möglich für das Paket keepassxc-2.7.6-1.fc37.x86_64
===================================================================================================================================
Paket                     Architektur           Version                          Paketquelle                                Größe
===================================================================================================================================
Pakete mit Konflikten werden übersprungen:
(fügen Sie »--best --allowerasing« zur Befehlszeile hinzu, um die Aktualisierung zu erzwingen):
qt5-qtbase                x86_64                5.15.10-9.fc37                   updates                                    3.5 M
unixODBC                  x86_64                2.3.11-1.rh                      packages-microsoft-com-prod                274 k
Pakete mit nicht auflösbaren Abhängigkeiten werden übersprungen:
keepassxc                 x86_64                2.7.6-2.fc37                     updates                                    7.3 M

Transaktionszusammenfassung
===================================================================================================================================
Überspringen  3 Pakete

Nichts zu tun.
Fertig!
```

Comment: OK, the repo copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:taw:element was easy to solve. Even for me :-)
After removing Element i could  remove that repo as well and install element via flatpak.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems a `sudo dnf update --allowerasing --best` does it. Not that i would knew what that means, but the upgrade went through and now everything seems OK.